# Display a label instead of returning a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is the relevant code of my View:

```
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nickName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.nickName, new { @class = "RegisterControls" })
        <br /><br />

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.email)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.email, new { @class = "RegisterControls" })
        <br /><br />            

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.password)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.password, new { @class = "RegisterControls" })
```

And Action method:

```
public ActionResult RegisterNewUser(string uName, string email, string password)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Register";

        if (!users.RegisterUser(uName, email, password))
        {
            ViewBag.DeniedMsg = "A user with that email already exists";
            return; //This doesn't work, as I should return a View
        }            
        return PartialView("_Register");            
    }
```

If a user types in an already existing email upon registering (and when clicking the link that says "Create account", I want to just add a label saying that the email already exists, and NOT returning an entire view. See my action method for (hopefully) clearity.

The create account link:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Create account", "CheckifUserEmailExists", "RegisteredUsers", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "updaterDiv" }, new { @class = "actionButtons" })
```

Actually, more generally. If someone types in something in a text box, you will call the action method in the proper Controller. But this Action method always returns a view. But what if you just want to display a message to that user (e.i. saying "account created") and staying on the same view. How do you handle this? I can't do this, since I have to return a view, but I want to stay on the same view, and display the message there

Comment: Your sending a password to a GET method so anyone can view the users password by  looking at the browsers history! Follow normal patterns and make a POST. You can handle the email on the client side using a `[Remote]` attribute (refer [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28VS.98%29.aspx)), but you first need to learn some basics. Study the code in the `AccountController` when you create a new app in VS.

Comment: Simply change your `RegisterNewUser` action to accept `httppost` so that you don't need to have parameters as posted object will be available in Request. And then just pass that object again to your partial view (your partial view again has to be strongly typed) and you will see the prev. entered values will get displayed again :)

Answer (score 1):

Create one more action to return string. Like:

```
public string UserExistsMsg(string msg)
{
    return msg;
}
```

And change your `RegisterNewUser` action like this:

```
public ActionResult RegisterNewUser(string uName, string email, string password)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Register";

        if (!users.RegisterUser(uName, email, password))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("UserExistsMsg", "A user with that email already exists");
        }
        return PartialView("_Register");            
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Though it's a little unclear to me where my ViewBag message is displayed. It says RedirectToction, but how can I merge my ViewBag message in? Thanks again

Comment: Please, if some one has an approach to this, share. I have not solved it yet. I don't want to get redirected if the email already exists, but rather just stay on the same view, and display a label (ViewBag) that tells the user to provide another email

Comment: @user1960836, Sorry for delay, I did not see your reply. Please look at the second answer, I hope it would work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Change your RegisterNewUser action like this:

```
public ActionResult RegisterNewUser(string uName, string email, string password)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Register";
        String msg = "";
        if (!users.RegisterUser(uName, email, password))
        {
            msg = "A user with that email already exists";
        }
        ViewBag.DeniedMsg = msg;
        return PartialView("_Register");            
    }
```

And print the ViewBag string message at the top of partial view. Like:

```
@VeiwBag.DeniedMsg
```

If user doesn't exist, nothing will get printed.

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful. I still have the problem that a postback is made, so if user does exist, it will return  the register page again by a postback, so everything he entered in the form will be lost. This is why I was trying to avoid returning the view. Is there a way I can keep the data that the user provided in the form, so that he does not have to type them over again?

Comment: Simply change your `RegisterNewUser` action to accept `httppost` so that you don't need to have parameters as posted object will be available in Request. And then just pass that object again to your partial view (your partial view again has to be strongly typed) and you will see the prev. entered values will get displayed again :)